# What's the purpose of combining coroutine contexts in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-android-extensions

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html#combining-context-elements

The official document says I can combine some coroutine contexts, but what's the purpose of doing so and what's the effect?
Does that mean the coroutine's lifecycle is confined to both contexts?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you are confusing `CoroutineContext` and `CoroutineDispatcher` (possibly also `CoroutineScope`). Dispatcher is only one kind of Context. Others can be eg. `Job`, `CoroutineName`, `CoroutineExceptionHandler`. You can combine multiple of these - eg. to set dispatcher and error handler - but only have one of each type.

It does not make sense to combine multiple dispatchers, the only the last one will be applied.

I found [the talk Coroutines! Gotta catch 'em all! by Florina Muntenescu & Manuel Vivo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w0kfnydnFWI&list=PLQ176FUIyIUY6SKGl3Cj9yeYibBuRr3Hl&index=11&t=0s) from KotlinConf 2019 explaining some of this quite well.

Answer (score 9):

> I can combine some coroutine contexts, but what's the purpose of doing so and what's the effect?

A coroutine context is basically an immutable map. When you combine two immutable maps, you get a map containing all the keys of the constituent maps. Obviously, if both maps contain a given key, the resulting map can't contain it twice. Instead the right-hand map takes precedence.

A slight twist on the map paradigm is that you don't put (key, value) pairs into a context, instead every value you put already has a key associated with it. That's why every context element is already a context itself.

For example, these are two full-blown contexts:

```
val ioCtx = Dispatchers.IO
val jobCtx = Job()
```

You can combine them:

```
val ioAndJob = ioCtx + jobCtx
```

You can access an element by key:

```
val job = ioAndJob[Job]
```

You can combine contexts with colliding keys:

```
val defaultAndJob = ioAndJob + Dispatchers.Default
```

> Does that mean the coroutine's lifecycle is confined to both contexts?

A coroutine context doesn't confine a coroutine lifecycle. Some outside agency is required to cancel the job in the coroutine context. You have probably confused this with `CoroutineScope` which takes care of this concern. `CoroutineScope` is just an object with a single property, `coroutineContext`, but since coroutine builders such as `launch` or `async` take it as a receiver, it makes it easy to build a coroutine hierarchy that can be centrally cancelled.